# What happen to http request when applicationWillResignActive or applicationDidEnterBackground

Tags: ios

When the app is doing an http request and the user receive suddenly a phone call and put the app in background (so event like `applicationWillResignActive` and `applicationDidEnterBackground` will be fired), what's happen to the current **active http request** ? do i need to worry about it (calling for example `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`) or the system will at least let the current http request finish successfully ?

Comment: there is a time limit 10 minutes for any app run in the background, after that OS kills your app. Best way to add backgroundsession configuration for the task.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you didn't opt-in for multitasking, then your HTTP call will continue for *a while*: According to [docs on applicationDidEnterBackground](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622997-applicationdidenterbackground), you have about 5 seconds to complete any ongoing tasks, hence all unfinished HTTP calls will halt when the actual suspension occurs. The respective sockets will then timeout.

If you need more time, use background downloads or begin a [background task](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623031-beginbackgroundtask).